# Write a program that reads two sets of integer elements (10 elements for each set) and finds the intersection of two sets

Tags: c++, set-intersection

How can I finish my code below? Where should I add **isEmpty**? And how to just print **"The Intersected Elements of Set A and B are:"** once only?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int A[10], B[10];

    cout << "Enter 10 Elements of Set A:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        cin >> A[i];
    }
    cout << "Enter 10 Elements of Set B:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        cin >> B[i];
    }

    bool isFirstIntersectedElem = true;
    bool isEmpty = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            if (A[i] == B[j]) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10 && isFirstIntersectedElem; i++) {
                    if (A[i] != B[i]) {
                        isFirstIntersectedElem = false;
                    }
                }

                if (isFirstIntersectedElem) {
                    cout << "The Intersected Elements of Set A and B are:" << endl;
                    cout << A[i] << " ";
                }
                else {
                    cout << "The IntersectedElement of Set A and B are not Found.";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the expected output:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cPvX.png)

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using [`std::set_intersection`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection)?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're mostly there. You can read in the numbers, and then you're using nested loops to check for each element in `A` if it's in `B`.

The best approach may be to create an array `C` of ten ints and a new counter variable initially set to zero. If you find an element in A that is in B you can store it in `C` and increment your counter. You'll have the intersection in `C` *and* the count of how long it is.

Answer (score 0):

[Don’t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721) write `using namespace std;`.

You can, however, in a CPP file (not H file) or inside a function put individual `using std::string;` etc.  (See [SF.7](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#sf7-dont-write-using-namespace-at-global-scope-in-a-header-file).)

---

Separate your "real code", the logic of finding the intersection in this case, from the input and output.  Write a **function** that takes inputs as parameters and returns a result.

So, don't print-as-you-go.  Rather, collect a new set for the result, which is eventually returned.

Then, the main code can see whether the result is an empty set and print something suitable, easily.

---

> Where should I add isEmpty?

What's it for?  It doesn't seem to be used at all.  Just delete it.

---

Rather than limiting your input to exactly ten values each, use a proper collection that holds any number of elements.  In fact, you should use a `std::set` which will automatically squish duplicates and give you a sorted view regardless of how it was input.

Use a ranged `for` loop, rather than iterating via subscripts.

Don't duplicate the identical input code for the two input values.  Make a common function to read *a* set, and call it twice.

Something like:

```
using setval = std::set<int>;

setval read_input() { ... }  // prompt user and read

setval intersection (const setval& left, const setval& right)
{
/* your main problem is solved here */
/* just calling std::set_intersection
  (see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection) is cheating!
  The exercise is to understand and write the logic for doing this.
  However, it would be smart to automate testing by comparing your 
  results against the library function! */
}

int main()
{
    setval A = read_input();
    setval B = read_input();
    auto I = intersection (A,B);
    if (I.empty()) cout << "No intersection.\n";
    else {
         // print the results
    }
}
```